# Membership contributions for existing organisations

Tags: wordpress, civimember, contributions

Our client wants to preload several thousand organisations, then have a user be able to search for an organisation when signing up for a membership. The user won't exist in Civi yet, so won't have a relationship to an organisation, so we need them to be able to select the organisation, have a membership created for that organisation, and an individual user account created, linked to that organisation.

We're using WordPress if that makes any difference to what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This extension allows you to set the 'organisation' field as an autocomplete

https://civicrm.org/extensions/public-autocomplete-of-organisation-names

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The extension works great for logged in users, but hooks into wp-admin/admin.php so anonymous users' requests get redirected to wp-login.php. I've raised it with the developer

Comment: are you sure it isn't just an extra permission you need to add to your settings

Comment: access AJAX API?